# EF dbContext IQueryable methods dependencies not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've tried to add a few helper methods to my dbContext class like this

```
public IQueryable<Tool> GetAllToolsInCompanyGroup(string userName)
{
    var user = GetUserByName(userName);
    return Tools.Where(t => Companies.Any(c => user.Company.CompanyGroupId == c.CompanyGroupId && c.Id == t.CompanyId));
}
```

But if I call that from my controller I get this exception:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'myNamespace.Models.Company'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

If i do the exact same thing in in my controller like this:

```
db.Tools.Where(t => db.Companies.Any(c => user.Company.CompanyGroupId == c.CompanyGroupId && c.Id == t.CompanyId))
```

it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using some joins like this:

```
var user = GetUserByName(userName);
var tools = from t in Tools
            join u in Users on t.CompanyId equals u.CompanyId
            join c in Companies on u.Company.CompanyGroupId equals c.CompanyGroup.Id
            select t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Tool class an entity class or DbContext class ?? because i guess that you are returning  "Tools" ( an entity class from your previous method and thats why it is throwing an exception

Comment: Tool is my POCO class with a FK reference to Company